# TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: javascript, fetch

Есть файл Token с запросом

```
export default async function Token(email, password) {
  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error('Could not fetch');
  }
  return fetch(`/api/login?pass=${password}&user=${email}`, {
    method: 'POST',
  })
}
```

Я импортирую функцию Token в login.js

```
import Token from '../requests';
import saveToken from '../token';

export default function login(email, password) {
  Token(`/api/login?pass=${password}&user=${email}`, {
      method: 'POST'
    })
    .then((res) => res.text())
    .then(saveToken)
    .catch(() => {
      alert('failed');
    });
}
```

После чего вешаю на кнопку авторизации данный запрос и в этом месте прилетает данная ошибка `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`.

```
login(email, password)
      .then(() => {
        history.push('/home');
      });
```

Любая помощь будет оценена.

Comment: Так у Вас же функция `login()` ничего не возвращает. Ну или, если угодно, возвращает `undefined`, у которого нет никакого метода `.then()`.

Comment: `getTokenData` - где определена эта функция?

Comment: Вместо getTokenData напишите return fetch

Comment: исправил, gettokendata - это token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как написали в комментариях, функция `login` возвращает `undefined`, у которого нет метода `then`. Нужно явно вернуть `Token`

```
import Token from '../requests';
import saveToken from '../token';

export default function login(email, password) {
  return Token(`/api/login?pass=${password}&user=${email}`, {
      method: 'POST'
    })
    .then((res) => res.text())
    .then(saveToken)
    .catch(() => {
      alert('failed');
    });
}

login(...).then(...);
```

Comment: большое вам спасибо, возможно вы могли бы мне еще подсказать на счет однйо проблемы. В данный момент не сохраняется токен в localstorage, что я написал не так в данном коде?

Comment: @quires задайте лучше отдельный вопрос, а то я не понял, о каком коде вы говорите